# Spread portion of code across multiple node in spark/scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, executors

I have file size of around 10 gb.
I need to extract the data & insert them into multiple hive tables.

I am able to accomplish using some preparsing/map functions in a single node.

Sample data :

```
Dept : HR
Emp name is Andrew lives in Colorodo
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Healthcare
DOJ : 06/04/2011
DOL : 09/21/2011
Project name : Retail
DOJ : 11/04/2011
DOL : 08/21/2013
Project name : Audit
DOJ : 09/11/2013
DOL : 09/01/2014
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016
Emp name is Alex lives in Texas
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Healthcare
DOJ : 06/04/2011
DOL : 09/21/2011
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016
Emp name is Mathew lives in California
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Healthcare
DOJ : 06/04/2011
DOL : 09/21/2011
Project name : Retail
DOJ : 11/04/2011
DOL : 08/21/2013
Project name : Audit
DOJ : 09/11/2013
DOL : 09/01/2014
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016

Dept : QC
Emp name is Nguyen lives in Nevada
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Healthcare
DOJ : 06/04/2011
DOL : 09/21/2011
Project name : Retail
DOJ : 11/04/2011
DOL : 08/21/2013
Project name : Audit
DOJ : 09/11/2013
DOL : 09/01/2014
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016
Emp name is Cassey lives in Newyork
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Healthcare
DOJ : 06/04/2011
DOL : 09/21/2011
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016
Emp name is Ronney lives in Alasca
DOB : 03/09/1958
Project name : Audit
DOJ : 09/11/2013
DOL : 09/01/2014
Project name : ContorlManagement
DOJ : 01/08/2015
DOL : 02/14/2016
```

Here is my code :

```
val inp =  sc.textFile("F:\\Softwares\\Spark\\Programs for td\\input\\sample.txt").collect().mkString(" ").replaceAll("""[\r\n]+""", " ")
     val pt1 = """(?s)Dept : .*?(?=\bDept : |$)""".r
     val pt2 = """(?s)Emp name : .*?(?=\bEmp name : |$)""".r
     val dname = """Dept : (\S+).*?""".r
     val emprec = """Emp name : (\S+) lives in (\S+) DOB : (\S+).*?""".r
     val prrec = """Project name : (\S+) DOJ : (\S+) DOL : (\S+) """.r
     var recs = pt1.findAllIn(inp)
     var rec1 = recs
```

After this rec1( Regex.MatchIterator) data becomes like below :

```
Dept : HR Emp name : Andrew lives in Colorodo DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name :Healthcare DOJ : 06/04/2011 DOL : 09/21/2011 Project name : Retail DOJ : 11/04/2011 DOL : 08/21/2013 Project name : Audit DOJ : 09/11/2013 DOL : 09/01/2014 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016 Emp name : Alex lives in Texas DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name : Healthcare DOJ : 06/04/2011 DOL : 09/21/2011 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016 Emp name : Mathew lives in California DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name : Healthcare DOJ : 06/04/2011 DOL : 09/21/2011 Project name : Retail DOJ : 11/04/2011 DOL : 08/21/2013 Project name : Audit DOJ : 09/11/2013 DOL : 09/01/2014 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016  



Dept : QC Emp name : Nguyen lives in Nevada DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name : Healthcare DOJ : 06/04/2011 DOL : 09/21/2011 Project name : Retail DOJ : 11/04/2011 DOL : 08/21/2013 Project name : Audit DOJ : 09/11/2013 DOL : 09/01/2014 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016 Emp name : Cassey lives in Newyork DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name : Healthcare DOJ : 06/04/2011 DOL : 09/21/2011 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016 Emp name : Ronney lives in Alasca DOB : 03/09/1958 Project name : Audit DOJ : 09/11/2013 DOL : 09/01/2014 Project name : ContorlManagement DOJ : 01/08/2015 DOL : 02/14/2016
```

i.e Each Dept data becomes its own row.
Sometimes it may vary between 300k - 400k rows.
Here is next portion of code which formats it & converts them into dataframe.(I am yet to code to insert this Df to hive. But I think, I can write this at bottom of this pgm .)

```
   var recfinal =  recs.map
      {
        e=>
 //  println(e)
      var dname(d) = e
   //    println(d)
      var rec2= pt2.findAllIn(e)

        var rec5 =rec2.map { k =>
    //   println(k)
                var emprec(ename,est,edob) = k
     //     println(ename,est,edob)
                var rec3 = prrec.findAllIn(k) 

               var rec4 =  rec3.map { j =>
                            var prrec(prjname,doj,dol) = j
                            var reclist = (d,ename,est,edob,prjname,doj,dol)
                             reclist
                           }
                .toList
                rec4
                  }
       .toList
       rec5

      }
    .flatMap(identity)
   .flatMap(identity)
  val rec9= recfinal.toSeq.toDF("dname","en","st","db","prj","dj","dl")
  rec9.show
```

1)How can I spread the second portion of code to multiple executors node & same time Data should also split equivally to get executed. Like I have 4 node cluster & each node should get 100K rows & execute the 2nd rtion of code alone. But At the end it all should be in one hive table.

Comment: If you can do `sc.textFile(...).collect().` to pre-process the data, why use spark at all?

Comment: I ll try my best to explain my case here. Please let me know if you need any specific info. I use 32gb RAM in each my machines. So I can process all data(~10GB) in single machine itself. But that takes more time. At the same I need pre process my file. Thatswhy I used collect. Once its pre processed , I am trying to spread them across the node & process it . so that it can do a parellal execution.

Comment: See my answer to your other question. Using Spark for this case doesn't seem a good fit. Use an alternative approach to make a spark-friendly input (like csv) and then load that into Spark for further processing (sql, hive, ...)
.

Comment: Okay. Thanks maasg.  I ll try that option as well. Thanks.